# How to convert a X and Y Velocity to one Velocity

Tags: javascript, math, vector

How would I go about converting an X and Y Velocity to one Velocity? I don't mean the angle just the velocity.

```js
var velocityX = some velocity;
var velocityY = some velocity;

// Convert the two X and Y velocities to one velocity
```

Comment: `I don't mean the angle just the velocity.` What is _just the velocity_? A vector also contains a direction, not just a length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take [`Math.hypot`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/hypot) with all velocities.

```
newVelocity = Math.hypot(velocityX, velocityY);
```

Answer (score 5):

Pythagoras would say

```
var velocity = Math.sqrt(velocityX*velocityX+velocityY*velocityX);
```

and he would be right.

Some other dude might add:

```
var angleInDegrees = Math.atan2(velocityX,velocityY)*180/Math.PI;
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you drop the direction, then it is just speed which is a scaler, whereas velocity is a vector.

You either are better off sticking with X and Y components, or having speed and angle.
Or
You are better off calling by what it becomes, which is speed.